# How to get a substring that comes after a certain character with LibreOffice's RIGHT function?

Tags: libreoffice

In the cell `A2` I have a surname `AARY` followed by an open parenthesis and a forename `(Max`.

|               A                              |                        B

------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |    Last name of the artist    |          First name of the artist 
------------------------------------------------------------------
2    |    AARY (Max                       | **Here goes the forename 'Max'**

I wanted to extract the forename without the parenthesis by using the command 
`=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("(",A2))`,
 but I get the `Err:508` error in bracketing.

When I add the bracket at the end of the formula, I get the `LibreOffice Calc found an error in the formula entered.`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commas may not work in LibreOffice depending on your settings. Semicolons work no matter what the settings are, so they are preferred unless interoperability with MS Excel is necessary.

```
=RIGHT(A2;LEN(A2)-SEARCH("(";A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Excel**:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("(",A2)+1,9999)
```

[image]

*(the 9999 should accommodate most names)*